# I am trying to get the slideshow images from JS and resize them in SCSS

Tags: javascript, sass, resize, slideshow

`The slideshow images in JS are blown up past the references of the screen. I am attempting to resize the said images in SCSS to fit all types of screens. Please bear with me as I am still learning as I go.`

**JavaScript**

```
var i = 0;
var images = [];
var slideTime = 3000; // 3 seconds

images [0] = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1639254241780-09c10527eb37?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=M3wzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE3MDU4™jY×ODR8&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=85';
images [1] = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1491438590914-bc09fcaaf77a?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=M3wzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE3MDU4MjYzMTN8&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=85';
images [2] = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1697490251825-0d6f7f3f7254?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=M3wzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE3MDUMjYzOT18&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=85';

function changePicture() {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[i] + ")";

  if (i < images.length - 1) {
    i++;
  } else {
    i = 0;
  ｝
  setTimeout (changePicture, slideTime);
｝
window.onload = changePicture;
```

[code pasted from this png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gL12Y.png)

**SCSS**

I am not sure what is the correct way to reference the code from above from JS in SCSS so here's what I've tried:

.images>0>"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1639254241780-09c10527eb37?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=M3wzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE3MDU4MjYxODR8&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=85";

.images>1>"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1491438590914-bc09fcaaf77a?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=M3wzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE3MDU4MjYzMTN8&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=85";

.images>2>"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1697490251825-0d6f7f3f7254?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=M3wzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE3MDU4MjYzOTl8&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=85"; {
background-size: cover;
}

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557

Comment: CSS and JavaScript have very different syntaxes. It seems like what you're trying to do is something like check for which image is currently loaded, and you could use those urls if you were to check for `.images img[src^="https://..."]` but really it seems as though you need to rethink how this is working. You could also add a class to the body and use that in the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to go around this, would be to pass the image URL's to an `<img>` tag within your HTML rather than setting the background of the body of the whole document to these images. That way you'll be able to add a class to that `<img>` tag and you'll be able to change the height and width of the images in your SCSS.

A tip for resizing images at all screen sizes is to use 'em' or '%' rather than pixels as these will scale the images along with the view port.